# IIS rewrite and redirect rules doesn't work on my site

Tags: asp.net, iis, github-pages

Hi have two problems using IIS rewrite and redirect rules in front of a web page hosted on GitHub Pages.

**Rewrite to GitHub Page**

**Update: Everything worked perfectly. As described later in this question, it was GitHub Pages that did the redirect to the canonical URL. Adding a rewrite appending the missing trailing slash before hitting GitHub Pages fixed it:**

```xml
<rule name="Add Trailing Slash" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*[^/]$" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern=".+?\.\w+$" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}/" />
</rule>
```

The site is hosted on GitHub Pages and available here: `http://elmahio.github.io/blog/`.

In order to rewrite requests to my proxy, I have added the following rewrite rule:

```xml
<rule name="Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^(.*)/.well-known/(.*)$"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://elmahio.github.io/blog/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

The rewrite rule works like a charm. But if anyone forget the trailing slash to an URL, it seems to redirect to the GitHub Page version. Example:

`https://blog.elmah.io/great-dot-net-conferences-to-attend` redirects to `http:// elmahio.github.io/blog/great-dot-net-conferences-to-attend/`

I can see that GitHub Pages automatically append the trailing slash if not there. This might even be the main problem, since my proxy rewrite to the GitHub one and then redirect to append the trailing slash.

Any ideas to how to fix this? Maybe add a redirect rule in my proxy, appending that slash before rewriting to GitHub Pages?

**Redirect to HTTPS**

**Update: Removing my custom redirect rule and enabling *HTTPS Only* on the *Custom domain* view on Azure, fixed this problem**

I want all requests made to a non-https URL, redirected to HTTPS. I have added a redirect rule to `web.config` like this:

```xml
<rule name="RedirectToHTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)"/>
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```

The rewrite rule works fine on URL's containing a path. Example:

http://blog.elmah.io/great-dot-net-conferences-to-attend/ redirects to https://blog.elmah.io/great-dot-net-conferences-to-attend/

But when visiting the front page (http://blog.elmah.io/ or http://blog.elmah.io) without HTTPS, I am not redirected to the HTTPS URL.

What could go wrong here?

Comment: Do you have other rules in your web.config? And you please include all your rules in your question. Looks like another rule is affecting.

Comment: I don't have other rules than these two. You can see the full source here: https://github.com/elmahio/Elmah.Io.ReverseProxy

Comment: Awesome, let me check it and come back with solution

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the issue on my PC. But just in case, can you try to remove `stopProcessing="true"` may be it will help

Comment: Removing stopProcessing doesn't help.

Comment: Can you reproduce it locally? or only in Azure?

Comment: Also Azure has this extension: https://blog.nicholasrogoff.com/2017/01/12/azure-app-service-force-redirect-from-http-to-https-the-easy-way/

Comment: And please keep in mind that you need to clear cache in your browser, before testing redirect. Because most browsers are caching 301 redirects.

Comment: I didn't try locally and must admit that I don't know how I would do that. I'll try to replace one of my rules with the extension and see if that changes anything. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162520/discussion-between-victor-leontyev-and-thomasardal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your rewrites are correct. Most probably issue exists because of GitHub pages. Try to do the following:

1) Create a rule to append trailing slash. You can find the example of rewrite rule in this thread [IIS URL Rewrite: Add trailing slash except for .html and .aspx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724455/iis-url-rewrite-add-trailing-slash-except-for-html-and-aspx/)

2) Instead of using rewrite rule for redirect to HTTPS, you can enable HTTPS Only on the Custom domain view on Azure